# MVC Razor helpers do not render proper ID and Name attributes for fields of interface derived classes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, razor, interface

I have a class which looks like this:

```
public class ApplicationFormModel
    {
        protected ApplicationFormModel()
        {
            CurrentStep = ApplicationSteps.PersonalInfo;
            PersonalInfoStep = new PersonalInfo();
        }

        public PersonalInfo PersonalInfoStep { get; set; }
        public IEducationalBackground EducationalBackgroundStep { get; set; }
        public IAboutYou AboutYouStep { get; set; }
        public IOther OtherStep { get; set; }
    }
```

where IEducationalBackground, IAboutYou, and IOther are interfaces. I do not use this class directly, but I use derived classes of this one which upon instantiation create the proper instances of EducationalBackgroundStep, AboutYouStep, and OtherStep.

In my view, I am using Razor Helpers such as

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => (model.EducationalBackgroundStep as ApplicationFormModels.EducationalBackgroundAA).University, new {@class = "form-control", type = "text", autocomplete = "off"})
```

The field 'University', for example, is NOT part of the Interface and I therefore need the cast to access it. ***Everything is fine for properties of the interface itself, but those which I need to cast for do not end up having the correct ID and Name properties.***

**For example, instead of EducationalBackgroundStep_University as ID, I only get University. This causes the form to not include this value when submitting it.**

I did not have this issue before when I used a base class instead of an interface, but then I had to include the EducationalBackgroundStep, AboutYouStep, and OtherStep in each derived class (and have it then of the correct derived type), but that is what I wanted to avoid.

Is there any way around this? Thank you very much!

Comment: The `DefaultModelBinder` will not bind to interfaces in you POST method. Are you using a custom ModelBinder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with the ID generation is because you are using casting (x as y) and the TextBoxFor expression handler can't determine what the original model property was (more to the point, it doesn't make sense to use the original model property as you're not using it any more, you're using the cast property)

Example fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/jQOSZA

```
    public class c1
    {
        public c2 c2 { get; set; }
    }

    public class c2
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public ActionResult View(string page, bool pre = false)
    {
        var model = new c1 { c2 = new c2 { Name = "xx" } };
        return View(model);
    }
```

View

```
@model HomeController.c1
@Html.TextBoxFor(x=>Model.c2.Name)
@Html.TextBoxFor(x=>(Model.c2 as HomeController.c2).Name)
```

The first textboxfor has ID `c2_Name` while the second has just `Name`

You have two options:

1) use concrete classes rather than interfaces for your *viewmodel*

2) don't use TextBoxFor and instead use TextBox and specify the ID manually (but then you'll lose refactoring)

```
@Html.TextBox("c2_Name", (Model.c2 as HomeController.c2).Name)
```

This will give you the ID you're expecting, but as @StephenMuecke rightly points out, this might not bind correctly when you do the POST - so you may still be stuck... but at least it answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

@freedomn-m explained to me why my code wouldn't work and he put me on the right track to find a solution, so he gets the accepted answer.

The workaround I used is the following - so I now have the following classes:

```
public class ApplicationFormViewModel {
    public PersonalInfo PersonalInfoStep { get; set; }

    // constructors which take the other classes and 
    // initialize these fields in an appropriate manner

    public IEducationalBackground EducationalBackgroundStep { get; set; }
    public IAboutYou AboutYouStep { get; set; }
    public IOther OtherStep { get; set; }
}

// in our case, XX can be one of 3 values, so we have 3 classes
public class ApplicationFormXX {
    public PersonalInfo PersonalInfoStep { get; set; }

    // constructor which take the ApplicationFormViewModel and 
    // initialize these fields in an appropriate manner

    public EducationalBackgroundXX EducationalBackgroundStep { get; set; }
    public AboutYouXX AboutYouStep { get; set; }
    public OtherXX OtherStep { get; set; }
}
```

To the main View I send the ApplicationFormViewModel and for each of the fields, I call a separate Partial View.

The Partial views render the common fields which are present in the Interfaces and then, depending on the type of the object held by the interface, it calls a different partial view which accepts the correct Model.

**Example:**

In the main View I have (NOTE: The actions return a partial view):

```
@model Applications.Models.ApplicationFormModels.ApplicationFormViewModel

// CODE, CODE, CODE

@Html.Action("RenderEducationalBackgroundStep", "ApplicationFormsLogic", routeValues: new {model = Model})
```

In the Partial View of for the EducationalBackgroundStep, I have:

```
@model ApplicationFormModels.ApplicationFormViewModel

// CODE, CODE, CODE

@{
    var educationalBackgroundType = Model.EducationalBackgroundStep.GetType();
    if (educationalBackgroundType == typeof(EducationalBackgroundXX))
    {
         <text>@Html.Partial("~\\Views\\Partials\\ApplicationForm\\Partials\\ApplicationSteps\\EducationalBackground\\_EducationalBackgroundXX.cshtml", new ApplicationFormModels.ApplicationFormModelXX { EducationalBackgroundStep = Model.EducationalBackgroundStep as EducationalBackgroundXX })</text>
    }
    // OTHER ELSE IF CASES
}
```

And then, the _EducationalBackgroundXX.cshtml partial view expects a model like this:

```
@model ApplicationFormModels.ApplicationFormModelXX
```

This way, **no casting** is required and everything works fine with the ModelBinder. Again, thank you @freedomn-m for setting me on the right track.

**NOTE:** In practice I need more fields than the ones presented here (for navigation and some custom logic), so actually all of these classes inherit an abstract base class (this makes it redundant to have the PersonalInfoStep declared in each of the classes, for example, because it can be inherited from the abstract base class). But for the intents and purposes of this method, what's present here suffices.